# Can I use apple pay for subscription purchasing of storage on cloud

Tags: ios, braintree, applepay

We are planning to make an application, in which user can upload their pictures and video on cloud storage(we will provide it). For cloud storage, we will provide the user with different storage purchase options like 50 GB, 100GB, etc. This purchase will be subscription based which is renewed monthly, quarterly and yearly.
 We want to use Apple Pay for this but not sure if Apple will approve this? So anyone has any idea, what is the right way to implement it.

Comment: Difficult to say. The only real way to find out is trying it. *"If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments"* - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#subscriptions

Comment: Look at what dropbox do with its subscription plans.

Comment: Only Apple can say, but i would say that if the cloud storage is available for use within the app (even if it is also available outside the app) then you will need to use in-app purchase. You can allow the user to log in and access storage that they have paid for outside the app through some other process/payment method but you cannot let the user access that payment method from the app. Look at how Netflix works; subscriptions from within the app use IAP, but you can log into the Netflix app and use a subscription you have paid for some other way